# How to count Partition key in Azure table storage?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-table-storage

How to get the count of partition key in Azure table storage? The performance needed to be considered.

Just need to get the total number of different partition on the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count rows within partition in Azure table storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977896/count-rows-within-partition-in-azure-table-storage)

Comment: Different. The link you provide is to count the rows in a partition. However, I just need to count the total numbers of partition

Comment: The approach would still remain the same. You will need to iterate through all the entities. 

What you would do is create a dictionary where key is the partition key value and the value will contain the count of entities having that partition key value.