# how to get the count using Storage Service URI

Tags: c#, azure-storage

I want to get the count by using the Azure Storage Service URI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-tables

i gone through this documentation, but i didn't find any solution for getting count. And also i have tried like this

https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/MyTable?$count

but i am not getting the count

Comment: try this as this works on OData https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/MyTable/$count

Comment: i have tried this one also bu i am getting HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is not count for Azure table storage. You should consider using the **Query Projection Feature**

> In addition, the projection feature will be useful in writing code that would count the number of entities in a certain table in a more efficient manner. We are working on providing Count() in the future, but until that is available Projection is useful since it will allow the transfer of a single property back to the client instead of the full row which makes the counting job more efficient. The code that highlights this usage is demonstrated in a later section.
>   Source: **https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2011/09/15/windows-azure-tables-introducing-upsert-and-query-projection/**

I'd also recommend checking this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977896/count-rows-within-partition-in-azure-table-storage)